# React + Apollo + cache + refetchQueries ; cache update gets overridden after mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm currently trying to use the Apollo cache system as the single source of truth for my application, as is recommended by the documentation. The first attempt I made was to store some map data that I can update and get through (fake) GraphQL queries, that will hit the cache instead of the backend server.

This is what my `resolvers.js` file looks like:

```
export const defaults = {
    MapState: {
        __typename: 'MapState',
        activable: false,
        activeZones: [],
        clickableZones: [],
    },
};

export const resolvers = {
    Mutation: {
        updateMapState: (_, parameters, { cache, client }) => {
            const query = gql`
                query GetMapState {
                    MapState @client {
                        activable
                        activeZones
                        clickableZones
                    }
                }
            `;
            let data = client.readQuery({ query });
            if (parameters.activable) {
                data.MapState.activable = parameters.activable;
            }
            if (parameters.activeZones) {
                data.MapState.activeZones = parameters.activeZones;
            }
            if (parameters.clickableZones) {
                data.MapState.clickableZones = parameters.clickableZones;
            }

            client.writeQuery({ query, data });

            return null;
        },
    }
};

export const typeDefs = gql`
  type MapState {
    activable: Boolean!
    activeZones: [String!]!
    clickableZones: [String!]!
  }
  ...
`;
```

And here is the call I make to update:

```
ApolloClient.mutate({
    variables: {
        activable: activable,
        activeZones: activeZones,
        clickableZones: clickableZones,
    },
    mutation: UPDATE_MAP_STATE,
    refetchQueries: ['GetMapState'],
});
```

The map state data does not (and should not) have an associated `id`. Thus, Apollo is not able, by default, to update components that fetch the map state data - which is the case of my `Map` component through a query called `GetMapState`.

In such cases, [the documentation indicates `refetchQueries` should be used](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching/#updating-after-a-mutation).

So, this works, kind of. When I use `updateMapState`, the cache is indeed updated. And `refetchQueries` indeed fetches the content of the map state from the Apollo Cache. **HOWEVER** (and this is the pain point), after `updateMapState` and before `refetchQueries`, somehow the cache data that was just written gets un-written through a call to `InMemoryCache.write`, with the default values, that I have trouble tracing.

Any idea why this call is made? How can I fix that? Seems like a pretty straightforward problem, but my inexperience with the stack does not allow me to understand what is happening.

Using either `client` or `cache` in `resolver.js` yields the same result.

If I remove `refetchQueries`, the cache is in the state I want, but my component is not reloaded automatically. If I add it, the component is reloaded, but my cache gets overridden.

**EDIT**: When `refetchQueries` is not enabled, this is what I have in my cache (only interesting parts shown):

```
ROOT_QUERY
    MapState: MapState
    activable: false
    activeZones: {"type":"json","json":["COUNTRY"]}
    clickableZones: {"type":"json","json":[]}
ROOT_MUTATION
    updateMapState({"activable":false,"activeZones":["COUNTRY"],"clickableZones":[]}): null
```

There is no key `MapState:something`

Comment: Using `refetchQueries` doesn't really make sense in the context of mutating local state. You're already manipulating the cache directly inside the resolver -- there's no need to refetch anything. The call to `writeQuery` should be sufficient to trigger any updates to existing query observers.

Comment: It does, regardless of this being the local state or not. The usual strategy of Apollo is to use the identifier to build the cache key, something it cannot do if no identifier exist. `refetchQueries` allows to indicate manually which queries will require a refresh. The documentation specifically indicates `refetchQueries` as a way to address this.

Comment: Apollo will still generate a cache key, it will just be missing the "id" portion and look something like this: `MapState:undefined`. What the [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching/#updating-after-a-mutation) states is that relying on automatic cache updates based on the cache key is *insufficient* in some cases and recommends `refetchQueries` as a possible solution in these scenarios. The (usually better) alternative to `refetchQueries` is to manipulate the cache directly inside the `update` callback. Neither is necessary for local state.

Comment: My point is that for local state, as long as you've correctly implemented your resolver, it should be sufficient to call `mutate` to trigger updates to any relevant `Query` components in your app. If you're *not* seeing that, there's something else going on (like bad code inside the resolver, using `client.query` instead of `watchQuery`/`Query` component, etc.).

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks